# Java: Grabbing a class that isn't a part of your program

Tags: java, class, reflection

So say I have two applications. The first application contains one file and displays the following code:

```
public class Ball{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("You have found the ball");
    }
}
```

The second application also contains one file:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class Human{  
    private static Method[] methods = null;

    public static void main(String[] args){
      try{
          Class ball = Class.forName("sports.soccer.Ball"); // Error occurs here
          methods = ball.getDeclaredMethods();
          for (int i = 0; i < methods.length; i++) {
              methods[i].setAccessible(true);
          }
          //ball.main(); //This also doesn't work but I will read more on how to do this.
      }
      catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
}
```

In the location where the Human.class is, there is a folder called sports, which contains a folder called soccer, which contains a copy of the Ball.class from the first application. Compiling the program works fine enough, however when i go to run it produced the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sports/soccer/ball (w
rong name: Ball)

//The rest of the error
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:14
2)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:455)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:367)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:259)
        at Human.main(Human.java:8)
Press any key to continue . . .
```

From looking at the first error, and doing a bit of searching it's apparent it cant find the class file, but I'm confused as to why it can't. Is it simply a packaging error, or am I trying to grab the class the wrong way?

Links to the documentation I'm basing my code off of:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/class/classNew.html

Comment: Hmmmm `wrong name: Ball`

Comment: Does the first class have a package defined?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I'm confused as to what that actually means, as the name of the class file **is** Ball :/

Comment: @FedericoNafria No it doesn't. It's been compiled as a separate application and is not buried within any folders originally.

Comment: You seem to have omitted the package declarations in your source code.  That, and the paths of the generated class files, are critical pieces of information.  If you don't have package declarations in your source files, then you should go back to the basic Java tutorials and read up on packages and how the directory structure needs to mirror the package declarations.

Comment: If the Ball Class does not have a package defined, its name is `Ball`, not `sports.soccer.Ball`. If you want it to be `sports.soccer.Ball`you should declare its package `sports.soccer`

Comment: It worked thank you both :). I guess I should go back and read up on packaging then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the following changers and run your code again,

1. Declare the packages inside of both classes
2. Compile the application which is having the Ball class
3. Compile the application which is having the Human class
4. Run the Human class

Additionally,
Main method in a class is getting a String Array as a parameter. That is why ball.main() is not executing.Also main method of a class is a static method. We do not want to create an object to call a static method.

I had tested above steps and it is worked fine.

---

package sport.soccer;

public class Ball {

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      System.out.println("You have found the ball");
  }
```

}

---

package Man;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class Human {

```
 private static Method[] methods ;

 public static void main(String[] args){
    try{
        Class ball = Class.forName("sport.soccer.Ball"); 
        methods = ball.getDeclaredMethods();
        for (int i = 0; i < methods.length; i++) {
            methods[i].setAccessible(true);
        }
        sport.soccer.Ball.main(new String[]{}); 
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

}

---

Good Luck!!!

Comment: Thank you :) I had no idea you could package classes even if they weren't specifically in those folders defined by the package. You've saved me an arm and a leg.

Comment: Your well come. If it is working find please vote up my answer and mark as it is correct. Thanks and Good Luck